# C# Linq - Nested expression parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ expression which calls another expression which also calls another expression...

```
public static Expression<Func<Models.Order, Models.Product,decimal?>> _ExpressionOfGetCounterValue
{
    get
    {
        var _getAmountProxy = Product._ExpressionOfGetAmount;
        var _convertQuantityProxy = Product._ExpressionOfConvertQuantity;

        Expression<Func<Models.Order, Models.Product, decimal?>> cv =
            (order,product) => (
                _getAmountProxy.Invoke(
                    order.Product,
                    _convertQuantityProxy.Invoke(order.Product,order.Quantity), 
                    order.Product.Price));

        return cv;
    }
}

public static Expression<Func<Models.Product, decimal?, decimal?>> _ExpressionOfConvertQuantity
{
    get
    {
        Expression<Func<Models.Product, decimal?, decimal?>> convertQuantity =
            (product, quantity) => ModelEntities.DoubleToDecimal(
                                       ModelEntities.DecimalToDouble(quantity.Value)
                                     * Math.Pow(10.0, ModelEntities.DecimalToDouble(product.QuantityDecimals))
                                   );

        return convertQuantity;
    }
}
```

When executing this, I get an error InvalidOperationException: The parameter 'order' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

This exception comes from _convertQuantityProxy .Invoke(order.Product,order.Quantity) 
How can I pass the original parameter "order" to this call ?
Please note that I use LinqKit / AsExpandable() function.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide code related to _ExpressionOfConvertQuantity?

Comment: `public static Expression<Func<Models.Product, decimal?, decimal?>> _ExpressionOfConvertQuantity
        {
            get
            {
                Expression<Func<Models.Product, decimal?, decimal?>> convertQuantity =
                    (product, quantity) => ModelEntities.DoubleToDecimal(
                            (ModelEntities.DecimalToDouble(quantity.Value) * Math.Pow(10.0, ModelEntities.DecimalToDouble(product.QuantityDecimals)))
                        );
                return convertQuantity;
            }
        }`

Comment: @user1756338: I moved your code to the question, where it belongs. It shouldn't be in the comments, just an FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found, I have to return
return cv.Expand();